# A very famous person

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Complete the diagram below (at the bottom) exactly the way it's intended. With pictures only. Good luck!

---

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe one way to answer this question would be:

> [image: 5 pictures of celebrities whose first names begin J-E-S-U-S]

However, something is awry (read on for an explanation...).

First, identify the pictured celebrities:

> [image: Celebrities identified]

Now notice that:

> The initials of their first names spell out 6 further names (of the same gender as the images used to spell them out):
>
>  Joachim
>  Rachel
>  Joseph
>  Jacob
>  Mary
>  Anne

These can be arranged in the bottom diagram as follows, positioning the respective genders as indicated by the symbols at the top of the puzzle:

> [image: Family tree of... er...]

However, there is a small complication here...

> What we have here is a family tree of sorts, with the left-hand side representing the lineage of **Mary, the mother of Jesus** and the right-hand side representing the lineage of **Joseph... from the Old Testament**. I suspect a Googling error may have been made by the OP when creating the puzzle, intending for these to be the parents of *Joseph, husband of Mary*.
>
>  Whatever has happened here, I suspect the intended answer to replace the question mark is the 'very famous person' **JESUS**, spelled out in my answer by the male names:
>
>  Jeff Bridges
>  Eric Cantona
>  Simon Cowell
>  Usain Bolt
>  Sebastien Coe

Comment: :D Didn't see that! But now that I double check I see that rot13(Enpury vf gur zbgure bs Wbfrcu (sebz byq grfgnzrag), yvxr lbh fnvq, fb V jnf pbzcyrgryl jebat. Ohg **Wnpbo** BE Uryv jnf pbafvqrerq gur sngure bs Wbfrcu uhfonaq bs Znel. Cebonoyl jul gur zvfgnxr. Pna'g svaq gur anzr bs gur zbgure gubhtu.

Comment: Despite the mistake, your answer is correct of course, so well done for solving it anyways!

Comment: @Prim3numbah Yes, precisely - that was really throwing me, and all I could think to conclude was that this had happened. Your intention was plain to see at least :)

Comment: I suppose you could've gone with rot13(Wnzrf, oebgure bs Wrfhf, fvapr Wbfrcu vf hanzovthbhfyl uvf sngure, ohg V thrff ur'f abg nyy gung snzbhf ol pbzcnevfba.)